# OpenCV 3D camera calibration with four cameras

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

I am looking to do an image unwrapping of a cylindric object (like a printed label on a bottle).
I will acquire four images using four cameras at 90 degrees.
I need to calibrate the cameras in the 3D space, in order to get the extrinsic poses of the cameras to reconstruct the 2D unwrapped image.
I can find only OpenCV single 3D camera calibration examples. Is there an example with multiple (maybe more than two...) cameras somewhere?

Comment: What is your question? If you can do single, why can't you do four one-by-one?

Comment: I have working code fr that, that uses other vendor-proprietary APIs; you have to collect 5 grid poses for each camera (4 images per pose for a total of 80 images and 80 pixels/world correspondencies). Than you have to use all of them in a single `cf3DCalibrateCameras` API call to calibrate the four cameras together and get the extrinsic poses. I am looking for a similar OpenCv sample, if available.